# Is there a Time Slider feature in MapInfo?

Tags: mapinfo, time, animation

Is there an Time Slider Feature in MapInfo?  The only conclusion I have found in my research is that you have to buy the MapInfo Profiler arm?

Comment: MapInfo currently does not support this functionality.  What is the MapInfo Profiler Arm?  Do you mean the Crime Profiler?  What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

No, not in the standard version of MapInfo Professional.

Of course you could write one in MapBasic reasonably easily given time and effort.